# What is the purpose of unknown-device tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am unable to understand the use of [unknown-device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unknown-device) tag.

Please explain about the purpose of the tag and also explain if it is needed right now or useless.

Comment: I would say it serves no purpose whatsoever and should be removed

Comment: The definition on the tag wiki is pretty straight-forward. It is for problems associated with unknown devices that show up as attached to the system, but have no "device driver, description, identification to their name" -from the [Tag Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/unknown-device/info). Just added it for context. As far as following, I don't see anyone following this one any time soon. XD  May be useful in searches? Honestly, of the 16 uses, it looks like more than half are incorrect uses, so I'd say delete. Causes more problems than it solves.